# Mercurial Pushing Error

Tags: asp.net, mercurial, tortoisehg

I make a project (WebApplication) in a VS with Mercurial (TortoiseHG). It works when I make a commit, and when I press Outgoing it shows changes, but when I press PUSH it return this

```
[Push started]

pushing to https://IlfatZalyaletdinov:***@bitbucket.org/sofoilsoftwaregroup/webgui
[Error: abort: push creates new remote head 31a052127404!]

searching for changes

[Error: (merge or see "hg help push" for details about pushing new heads)]

new remote heads on branch 'default'

new remote head 31a052127404

[Operation completed. Exit code: 255]
```

I made same things with a desktop application and it worked. Maybe Mercurial can't work with WebApplication?

Answer (score 3):

Mercurial doesn't care whether you push WebApplication, Desktop application or any other type of project. Mercurial works with files.

About your case:

1. Check if you have any changes in your remote repository via `hg pull`. If you have any, merge your changes with changes in remote repository and then try to push once again.
2. Check if you have multiple heads in your local repository. If so, merge heads and then push changes.